# Authenticating Gmail addon user

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, gmail-addons

My Gmail Addon is making a request to an external server.
I want to make sure on the server that it's really the user / the addon.

How can I do that? can I save a token in the addon that can't be tampered with?
(The addon interact with Google servers, can I take advantage on that?)

Authenticating the user (email address) in our server can also be of great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can authenticate the user by passing the accessToken & emailId of the user to our server, get the google profile of the user using this access token by making [Google UserInfo API](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json) call, validate the email id from this profile against the emailId that is passed from Gmail add-on. If they both are same, you can treat it is a valid authentication. This process is similar to **SIGNIN WITH GMAIL** feature which we see in all apps nowadays.

Once it is authenticated, you can return the application session id to the add-on which we can save it in the user cache. This session id we can use to fetch our app data.

```
  CacheService.getUserCache().put("sid", <sessionId>);
```

Comment: Hi, i am looking for something similar as the quest. i have a doubt. how to get currently loggedin user's access token and email in addon? i am new to google apps script. any reference would be appriciated.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'd love to know how to get this access token in the plugin

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2